# ParametricPlot Question

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I want to graph more than two, lets say 5 different `ParametricPlot`-s all in terms of different time variables. Is there any way to do this, such that they all show up on the same plot? For example, I want to plot:

- `{3Cos[a],4Sin[a]}`.. on some interval,
- `{4Cos[b],5Sin[b]}`.. on some interval,
- `{5Cos[c],6Sin[c]}`.. on some interval,
- `{6Cos[d],7Sin[d]}`.. on some interval,
- `{7Cos[e],8Sin[e]}`.. on some interval,

all on one picture.

Thank You Very Much.

Comment: Check out `Show`, note that the order matters (`Show`
 uses the options from the first graphic)

Answer (score 4):

Combine them using [`Show[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html).

An example:

```
a1 = ParametricPlot[{3 Cos[a], 4 Sin[a]}, {a, 0, π}];

a2 = ParametricPlot[{4 Cos[b], 5 Sin[b]}, {b, 0, π/2}, 
     PlotStyle -> Green];

a3 = ParametricPlot[{5 Cos[c], 6 Sin[c]}, {c, 0, π/4}, 
     PlotStyle -> Purple];

a4 = ParametricPlot[{6 Cos[d], 7 Sin[d]}, {d, 0, π/8}, 
     PlotStyle -> Brown];

a5 = ParametricPlot[{7 Cos[e], 8 Sin[e]}, {e, 0, π/16}, 
     PlotStyle -> Cyan];

Show[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: Plot]